# Is to possible to fix errors in the comments of check-ins that are linked to JetBrains YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

**Background**

Our continous integration setup is TFS as source control, TeamCity as build, and YouTrack for issue management.  All these are linked together through the tight integration of TeamCity and YouTrack and through the comments mechanism of check-ins via TFS.

This means that a comment check-in of "PROJECT-1 added xyz functionality" would automatically associate the check-in and associated team city build with the issue in YouTrack.

We have set this up so all check-ins have to be associated with a YouTrack issue and a custom check-in policy uses the YouTrack .NET API (https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackSharp) to communicate with YouTrack and ensure that the comments for each check-in contains a valid YouTrack Id.

The problem we have is that it is still too easy to get the ID wrong in the comments i.e. typing in PROJECT-2 instead of PROJECT-1 and associating a check-in with the wrong issue.

**Question**

Is there a way to fix these issues by re-associating the check-in with the correct issue, either by:

- changing the changeset comments in the source control system and doing something so that YouTrack picks these changes up and reflects the changes, or;
- manually editing in YouTrack to move the change to the correct issue
  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible, you may, however, vote for the respective [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-4883) to speed up it's implementation.

Alexander

Comment: Please, anyone who is experiencing this issue, vote up! (on the JetBrains YouTrack site linked above)

Answer (score 1):

For the first option, you've mentioned, there is a request in TeamCity: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-1619

Comment: Yes, issue [http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-4883](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-4883) seems to be a duplicate of issue [http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-1619](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-1619).  Hopefully JetBrains will amalgamate and consider the extra weight of argument for introducing this feature.